# Use iterated list element to name variable in loop

Tags: python, list

I've browsed related questions but couldn't find one that exactly matched my use case.

I have created two lists (`plist`, `rlist`):

```
list1 = [str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(101)]
plist = ['p{0}'.format(element) for element in list1]

rlist = [str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(51)]
rlist = ['r{0}'.format(element) for element in rlist]
```

Each list looks like this:

```
>>> plist
['p00', 'p01', 'p02', 'p03'...'p100']

>>> rlist
['r00', 'r01', 'r02', 'r03'...'r50']
```

I have set up some nested for loops to create permutations of the list elements. The idea is to take each element of the `plist` and combine it with each and every element of the `rlist`. The process repeats until the `plist` is exhausted.

```
for pitem in range(len(plist)):
    vsdata = []
    for ritem in range(pitem, len(rlist)):
        if pitem == ritem:
            print("skipped")
        else:
            item1 = plist[pitem]
            item2 = rlist[ritem]
            vsdata.append([str(item1),str(item2)])
            print(item1 + " and " + item2)
```

Which yields:

```
skipped
p00 and r01
p00 and r02
p00 and r03
p00 and r04
p00 and r05
p00 and r06
p00 and r07
p00 and r08
p00 and r09
p00 and r10
...
p01 and r02
p01 and r03
p01 and r04
p01 and r05
p01 and r06
p01 and r07
p01 and r08
p01 and r09
p01 and r10
```

You'll notice I've also declared the empty list `vsdata` before the nested loop. This list should be appended with sets of permutations (eg. the first `plist` element combined with all the `rlist` elements) and saved, before the nested loop begins again and `vsdata` is overwritten with all the combinations involving the second element of `plist`.

Thus, I need to 'export' `vsdata` before this happens and name it using the relevant element of `plist`.

For example, after the second loop has run twice I should have two `vsdata` lists;

```
>>> vsdata_p00
[['p00', 'r02'], ['p00', 'r03'], ['p00', 'r04'], ['p00', 'r05'], ['p00', 'r06'], ['p00', 'r07'], ['p00', 'r08'], ['p00', 'r09'], ['p00', 'r10'] ...

>>> vsdata_p01
[['p01', 'r02'], ['p01', 'r03'], ['p01', 'r04'], ['p01', 'r05'], ['p01', 'r06'], ['p01', 'r07'], ['p01', 'r08'], ['p01', 'r09'], ['p01', 'r10'] ...
```

I've read about dictionaries and sets but can't fully understand how they might be implemented here. Ultimately I'd like all this data exported into a csv. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Don't leak data into your variable names. Are you sure you don't just want another layer or two of lists?

Comment: possibly, how do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this with a dictionary might work:

```
vsdatas = {}
for pitem in range(len(plist)):
    vsdata = []
    for ritem in range(pitem, len(rlist)):
        if pitem == ritem:
            print("skipped")
        else:
            item1 = plist[pitem]
            item2 = rlist[ritem]
            vsdata.append([str(item1),str(item2)])
            print(item1 + " and " + item2)
    vsdatas[plist[pitem]] = vsdata
```

To get the list of permutations for `"p01"`, for example, just access `vdatas["p01"]`.

In general, you don't want to dynamically create and name variables.

Comment: thanks - I gather there is an issue with what I'm doing but what would be the way of avoiding this situation?

Comment: @Beeman: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, unless you named *variables* dynamically. This is a dictionary, and it's a perfectly normal thing to use in Python (I'd suggest you read up on them -- they're widespread and *very* useful). I'm warning against what you said you wanted in the question, which would be dynamically naming *variables*.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before, you can use a dictionary. Also, everything can be done in one line (sacrificing a bit of readability):

```
vsdata = {'p'+str(p).zfill(2):[['p'+str(p).zfill(2), 'r'+str(r).zfill(2)] for r in range(p+1,51)] for p in range(101)}

print vsdata['p37']
# [['p37', 'r38'], ['p37', 'r39'], ['p37', 'r40'], ['p37', 'r41'], ['p37', 'r42'], ['p37', 'r43'], ['p37', 'r44'], ['p37', 'r45'], ['p37', 'r46'], ['p37', 'r47'], ['p37', 'r48'], ['p37', 'r49'], ['p37', 'r50']]
```

Comment: as I understand it this creates a dictionary but I need to pass the loop items into other functions (not listed in the example)

Comment: Indeed, this does not work if you need `plist` and `rlist` further in your code